What's this pink stuff between bathroom walls
Doing a bathroom renovation and there is this really light pink stuff between the bathroom walls. It's light pink/white and feels like Styrofoam, and it crumbles into a bunch of pieces if I squeeze it.
Some sort of insulation? But I didn't get any results from Google pink crumbly insulation.


Is this from an interior or exterior wall? It looks like someone tried to insulate the pipes to reduce the chance of freezing.

Interior. I have 2 bathrooms, back to back and this is the shared wall

If this is an interior wall, it may have been an attempt to reduce the noise from the drain pipes entering either room. Not a bad idea.
Filling the cavity with mineral wool will do the same thing.
